# Why does the object change its location after setting origin?

Tags: mirror, origin

I want to apply mirror modifier. My step:

[image: <code>[![enter image description here][1]][1]</code>]
For this example random vertex on eye:
[image]

[image]

[image]

What's wrong with this eyeball?

Comment: Check that you maybe accidentally added a keyframe to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No. Timeline is clear. Do you have another suggestion?